# What happens if you use Zarya's barrier on a Reinhardt with his barrier activated?

Tags: overwatch

If you apply Zarya's *Projected Barrier* (ally shield) on a Reinhardt with his *Barrier Field* (large shield) where does the damage get applied?

The *Projected Barrier* or the *Barrier Field*?

Comment: It would help if there was a reason given for the downvote so I could fix the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the damage is frontal and intercepted by the Barrier Field, the Field will absorb it. If the Barrier Field breaks, or the damage is from a direction Reinhardt is not blocking, then the Projected Barrier will absorb it. Only damage absorbed by the Projected Barrier will contribute to Zarya's Energy level.

Comment: So the `Barrier Field` sits out in front of the `Projected Barrier`? Like so

`O |` with the `O` representing Reinhardt and the `Projected Barrier`; and the `|` representing the `Barrier Field`?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: This is weird, I always thought the bubble pierced through the barrier a little. I distinctly remember getting charge from a Reinhardt being attacked from the front.

Comment: I guess it's possible. I know I've resented a lot of Reinhardts for not giving me energy, though. Could be that my enemies just don't like shooting at them to begin with.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer there's a difference between the art and the actual hitbox as far as the game engine is concerned. Even if the visuals of the bubble did pierce the barrier that may not represent the actual hitbox or the game logic that is considered when deciding what absorbs the shots. The game may check for barrier interceptions first, and if that check fails, then check for Zarya's bubble. Thus if the barrier check passes, the Zarya bubble check would never occur.

Comment: Makes me think we need to actually go in game at some stage and test this. But I haven't found a time to get 3 people together to trial it.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer the charge you got could be from Winston's `Tesla Cannon` or Symmetra's `Photon Projector` which go through his shield, or just general splash damage.